# Deploying ASP.NET Core webapp to Raspberry Pi for hosting fatal error

Tags: asp.net-core, raspberry-pi

I made a ASP.NET Core webapp and wish to deploy it to my raspberry pi and host it using NGINX. 
Am following the guide provided by Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2

and i am stuck at testing the app. This is what I did:

On my Windows PC in which I developed the webapp on, i went to the solution path:

`E:\testapp`

and ran the command on cmd:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

No errors was found and it was shown that my project L07 that was part of the testapp solution was successful.

But when i tried to test the app by running:

```
dotnet L07.Views.dll
```

it returned a fatal error:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required
 to execute the application was not found in 'E:\testapp\L07\bin\Release\net461\publish\'.
 Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, 
 add the E:\testapp\L07\bin\Release\net461\publish\L07.Views.runtimeconfig.json
 file specifying the appropriate framework.
```

.
I ignored that and transferred the entire E:\testapp\L07\bin\Release\net461\publish files to my raspberry pi and ran the same dotnet command and it gave me another fatal error which is:

```
A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/local/bin/host/fxr] does not exist
```

I feel that I am doing many wrong things here, anyone able to advise accordingly, as detailed as possible.

p/s not sure im i am posting this in the correct site

Comment: Do you compile [an self-contained and framework-dependent app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)? this determines if you need to install the .NET Core SDK/Runtime on the target system or not. Also you can't run applications targeting .NET Framework on Linux unless you target mono (and you don't use any API thats unavailable on mono)

Comment: @Tseng it is for self-contained. my pi has .NET Core SDK on it

Comment: Why does then `net461` appear in your error message? `E:\testapp\L07\bin\Release\net461\publish\`

Comment: Also post your csproj and what `RuntimeIdentifiers`/`RuntimeIdentifier` entries. Without it, its not self-contained. Also you can't self-contain .NET Framework targets, just .NET Core ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your .csproj and add proper runtime identifiers for release. Alternatively you can enter correct runtime identifier from command prompt

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) includes catalog of runtime identifiers

```
dotnet publish -runtime <yourRID> ...
```

As it is commented by @Tseng,  you need to decide whether you need self-contained or frame dependent application.

If you want to publish self-contained applciation then

```
dotnet publish -runtime <yourRID> --self-contained ...
```

Comment: just tried the solution you provided! I encountered the same error again. on my Windows PC, i cd to the ...\net461\any\publish directory and did the command "dotnet L07.Views.dll" . that is correct right?

Comment: *.runtimeconfig.json file could not be found in my directory. tried searching in the entire solution, none to be found as well. Tried googling but to no avail in rgds to this as well. // the only .json file i have that was created via dotnet publish is "L07.deps.json"

Comment: look at your bin folder :)

Comment: yes its not there. bin directory contains "Debug" and "Release" folders which leads to bin/*/net461/

Comment: you need to compile your project with `.net Core`. .Net Framework cannot be deployed on linux environments

Comment: Ahh realized my mistake, thank you!. my project was a ASP.NET Core web app but it was targeting to .NET Framework instead of .NET Core... fixed it.. thank you so much!