# ASP.NET Core 5: a fatal error ocurred creating the web host

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I created an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API solution with multiple projects as shown below:

[image]

The problem is in the `GeneXsys.Api` project. This is the `Program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Features;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Serilog;

namespace GeneXsys.Api
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.MachineName}.json", optional: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // See configuration details in appsettings.json
            // Verbose: Verbose is the noisiest level, rarely(if ever) enabled for a production app.
            // Debug:   Debug is used for internal system events that are not necessarily observable from the outside, 
            //          but useful when determining how something happened.
            // Information: Information events describe things happening in the system that correspond to its responsibilities 
            //              and functions.Generally these are the observable actions the system can perform.
            // Warning: When service is degraded, endangered, or may be behaving outside of its expected parameters, Warning level events are used.
            // Error: When functionality is unavailable or expectations broken, an Error event is used.
            // Fatal: The most critical level, Fatal events demand immediate attention.

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Logger.Information("Starting the web host ...");
                Console.WriteLine("Starting the web host ...");

                var host = CreateHost(args);
                var task = host.RunAsync();
                var server = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
                var addressFeature = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();

                foreach (var address in addressFeature.Addresses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Now listening on: {address}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Application started");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to shut down.");

                await task;
                //host.WaitForShutdown();
                //host.Run();

                Log.Logger.Information("Shutting down the web host ...");
                Console.WriteLine("Shutting down the web host ...");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Logger.Fatal(e, "A fatal error occurred creating the web host.");
                Console.WriteLine($"A fatal error occurred creating the web host: {e.StackTrace}");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHost CreateHost(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.ClearProviders();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .UseSerilog()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

This is Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var dbProvider = Configuration.GetValue("DbProviders:DefaultDbProvider", "SqlServer");

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
            ApplicationDbContext.ConfigureUseDbEngineBuilder(options, dbProvider, connectionString));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                //.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()
                //.AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddErrorDescriber<IdentityErrorMessageDescriber>();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = Configuration.GetValue<int>("Login:MaxIntentosFallidos");
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Configuration.GetValue<int>("Login:MaxMinutosBloqueo"));
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        });

        services.AddControllers(options => options.OutputFormatters.Add(new HtmlOutputFormatter()))
                .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
                {
                    // Change the default Model State Response Structure
                    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = c =>
                    {
                        string errors = String.Join(",", c.ModelState.Values
                                                                     .Where(c => c.Errors.Count > 0)
                                                                     .SelectMany(c => c.Errors)
                                                                     .Select(c => c.ErrorMessage));
                        return new BadRequestObjectResult(
                            new BaseResponseDto
                            {
                                Code = "Error",
                                Message = errors
                            });

                    };
                })
                .AddFluentValidation(options =>
                {
                    // Validators had to be moved to another Assembly different than this, otherwise in release will throw
                    // an exception when the Microsoft.EntitFrameworkCore.Design assembly is not found.
                    // That assembly is only used in design time for Scaffolding and is never published.
                    // That assembly was moved to Infrastructure project who is in charge of managing contexts topics.
                    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ApiData>();
                })
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    // Use the default property (Pascal) casing
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                });

        services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
        {
            // Specify the default API Version
            config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            // If the client hasn't specified the API version in the request, use the default API version number 
            config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            // Advertise the API versions supported for the particular endpoint
            config.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            //This is to generate the Default UI of Swagger Documentation
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "GeneXsys", Version = "v1.0" });
            // To Enable authorization using Swagger (JWT)
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your valid token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9\"",
            });
            options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        }
                    },
                    new string[] {}
                }
            });
        });

        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
            options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
        });

        // configure jwt authentication
        // For responses 401 Unauthorized when testing in Postman with https, set "anonymousAuthentication": true in launchSettings.json
        var jwtSecretKey = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Key");
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSecretKey);

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            SaveSigninToken = true,
            ValidateActor = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true, // Emisor
            ValidateAudience = true, // Target of the token
            ValidateLifetime = true, // Token lifetime (expiration)
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                    var userId = ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid)?.Value;
                    var user = userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                        context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                    {
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // TODO: Check the 'allows' granted for the requests (Origin, Method, headers, etc) and configure here a policy.
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true) // To let AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials work together
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                  .AllowCredentials()
            );
        });

        // Mappers had to be moved to another Assembly different than this, otherwise in release will throw
        // an exception when the Microsoft.EntitFrameworkCore.Design assembly is not found.
        // That assembly is only used in design time for Scaffolding and is never published.
        // That assembly was moved to Infrastructure project who is in charge of managing contexts topics.
        //services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ApiData));

        // Localization and Globalización Services (Languages)
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Cultura")),
                new CultureInfo("en-US")
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCultures[0]);
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.AddSingleton(HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.All }));
        services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork>(provider => new UnitOfWork(provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            //options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.100"));
        });

        /*string password = "";
        var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        var hashedPassword = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, password);*/
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // When using a reverse proxy server (e.g. Nginx, Apache, IIS, Kestrel),
        // this middleware redirects URIs and other security policies to work correctly.
        // This should run before other middleware so the best is to locate it here at the top.
        // Proxies running on loopback addresses 127.0.0.0/8, [::1], 127.0.0.1 are trusted by default.
        // If other truested proxies or networks handle requests between internet and the web server,
        // you could add them in ConfigureServices as KnownProxies or KnownNetworks.
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-dev");
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error"); // Launches de error action in the ErrorController, sends an RFC 7807-compliant payload to the client.
        }

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options => options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "GeneXsys v1.0"));
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "subareas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{subarea:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the app in debug mode by using VS2019, it works fine:

[image]

Also if I run by dotnet CLI:

[image]

However it fails when I deploy the app:

```
D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Aldemar\.Net Core\GeneXsys\GeneXsys.Api\bin\Release\net5.0\publish>dotnet GeneXsys.Api.dll
Starting the web host ...
A fatal error ocurred creating the web host:    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at GeneXsys.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Aldemar\.Net Core\GeneXsys\GeneXsys.Api\Program.cs:line 48

D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Aldemar\.Net Core\GeneXsys\GeneXsys.Api\bin\Release\net5.0\publish>
```

What I tried to do was to change the position of host.RunAsync() in Program.cs moving it down, this way:

```
            var host = CreateHost(args);
            var server = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
            var addressFeature = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();

            foreach (var address in addressFeature.Addresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Now listening on: {address}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Application started");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to shut down.");

            await host.RunAsync();
```

Again, it works fine when debugging by VS2019 or running dotnet run CLI command, however the exception error changed when I deployed and run by command:

```
D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Aldemar\.Net Core\GeneXsys\GeneXsys.Api\bin\Release\net5.0\publish>dotnet GeneXsys.Api.dll
Starting the web host ...
Application started
Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
A fatal error ocurred creating the web host:    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.GetChangeToken()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(ControllerActionEndpointDataSourceIdProvider dataSourceIdProvider, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory, OrderedEndpointsSequenceProvider orderSequence)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllerRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String name, String pattern, Object defaults, Object constraints, Object dataTokens)
   at GeneXsys.Api.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__5_1(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Aldemar\.Net Core\GeneXsys\GeneXsys.Api\Startup.cs:line 301
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at GeneXsys.Api.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Aldemar\.Net Core\GeneXsys\GeneXsys.Api\Startup.cs:line 299
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutoRegisterMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at GeneXsys.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Aldemar\.Net Core\GeneXsys\GeneXsys.Api\Program.cs:line 59
```

Why I used host.RunAsync() instead of normal Run() in Program.cs? Just to manage the steps of creating, loading, run and stopping of web host, showing the listening IP:port at that moment.

I appreciate any help

Comment: Have you tried different combinations of deployment like `Framework-Dependent` vs `Self-Contained` etc?

Comment: The issue might relate the Serilog, I tried to create a new application and test the code in your program.cs file, If I comment out the code related to the Serilog configuration, the application works well, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwd63.gif). You can try to change it. Besides, here is a similar thread, you can refer it: [Deploying ASP.NET Core webapp to Raspberry Pi for hosting fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917431/deploying-asp-net-core-webapp-to-raspberry-pi-for-hosting-fatal-error).

Comment: Zhi Lv, I tried to run as you showed commenting out serilog and published app throwed: A fatal error ocurred creating the web host:    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType) ... 
   at GeneXsys.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Aldemar\.Net Core\GeneXsys\GeneXsys.Api\Program.cs:line 48